# Altering plugin file

Tags: wordpress, plugins, exchange-server

I have a wordpress payment processor plugin that uses google finance to determine the exchange rate, but I want to use my own exchage rate instead of google finance.
Int he plugin file, I saw this function but did not know how to modify it...

```
function convert_currency_live($from_Currency, $to_Currency, $amount)
{
    $amount = urlencode($amount);
    $from_Currency = trim(strtoupper(urlencode($from_Currency)));
    $to_Currency = trim(strtoupper(urlencode($to_Currency)));

    if ($from_Currency == "TRL")  $from_Currency = "TRY"; // fix for Turkish Lyra
    if ($from_Currency == "ZWD")  $from_Currency = "ZWL"; // fix for Zimbabwe Dollar
    if ($from_Currency == "RIAL") $from_Currency = "IRR"; // fix for Iranian Rial

    $url = "https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=".$amount."&amp;from=".$from_Currency."&amp;to=".$to_Currency;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($res)
    {
        $data = explode('bld&gt;', $res);
        $data = explode($to_Currency, $data[1]);
        return round($data[0], ($to_Currency=="BTC"?5:2));
    }
    else return -1; 
}</pre>
```

The plugin converts every currency to dollar and my site uses my local currency.

Now I want to change this plugin to convert $1 USD = N376 NGN

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: as you may notice, the function take the amount and both currency .. you can simply create the same function and put your own code, and then rename this one so the plugin use yours.

Comment: you have the amount (which is only $) so just return the converted value

Comment: @temani-afif to do that is my problem now. Am not good in coding at all. If I can have a function I can use to replace this, it can save my ass. The plugin peaks any amount in my local currency from the woocommerce store, send it to google finance and peaks up the dollar value there to complete its job.

Comment: yes i know what the plugin do, but you are asking for someone to write the function for you ? i thought you having some issue .. i can do it for you as a freelance but i don't think this is the right place to ask this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to do this. If the exchange rate changes, then you'll need to update it in code. In any case, I think the easiest way to do this would be to detect if the $from_currency value is "USD" (or whatever the USD string would be) and if $to_Currency is "NGN" (Or whatever your local currency string would be). You can wrap the entire curl operation inside of an if-else statement and return a manual conversion if the value is "USD". So something like this:

```
function convert_currency_live($from_Currency, $to_Currency, $amount)
{
    $amount = urlencode($amount);
    $from_Currency = trim(strtoupper(urlencode($from_Currency)));
    $to_Currency = trim(strtoupper(urlencode($to_Currency)));

    if($from_Currency == "USD" && $to_Currency == "NGN"){
        return round(($amount * 376), 2);
    }else{

        if ($from_Currency == "TRL")  $from_Currency = "TRY"; // fix for Turkish Lyra
        if ($from_Currency == "ZWD")  $from_Currency = "ZWL"; // fix for Zimbabwe Dollar
        if ($from_Currency == "RIAL") $from_Currency = "IRR"; // fix for Iranian Rial

        $url = "https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=".$amount."&amp;from=".$from_Currency."&amp;to=".$to_Currency;

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if ($res)
        {
            $data = explode('bld&gt;', $res);
            $data = explode($to_Currency, $data[1]);
            return round($data[0], ($to_Currency=="BTC"?5:2));
        }else{
            return -1; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the direction. From currency is NGN which is the base currency of the site and the to currency is USD. In that case, it will be `
    if($from_Currency == "NGN" && $to_Currency == "USD"){
        return round(($amount * 376), 2);
    }` If am not mistaking.

Comment: I tried this code without success. It shows white screen on the payment page with continues buffering.